# How to determine if an interaction is warranted (in a generalized additive mixed model (GAMM))

Tags: interaction, model-selection, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm interested in determining if an interaction exists between my continuous (SL) and factor (fZone) covariate as it has some basis in biology. An anova() and BIC suggest no interaction is needed, but I've heard the p-values in the anova shouldn't be too heavily relied upon and BIC will almost always choose the most parsimonious model. The summary() command tells me there could be some non-linear relationship being captured in the interaction, but maybe the sample size isn't large enough to differentiate it from noise? I'm trying to not rely too much on the p-values and consider at the effect sizes, but the relationship seems to be right on the border of capturing some kind of potentially important signal. Maybe the model just lacks power? I can't quit tell.

I've used select=TRUE to kick-out terms if they aren't contributing much to the model as well as raised the "gamma" to 1.3 to add some extra smoothness, but it seems some non-linear relationship still remains (summary(smooth_inter_mod)) - but maybe I'm wrong and the effect isn't that impressive to keep in the model? Does the interaction seem justified or because the continuous variable SL is non-linear and highly significant it's making the interaction term seem important? I'm looking to infer a possible relationship, not prediction.

```
library(mgcv)
library(gratia)

> table(c_neb5$empty, c_neb5$fZone)
   
    Rankin West Whipray
  0    156  318      31
  1     45  118      11
    
no_inter_mod <- bam(empty ~
              SL +
              fZone +
              
              s(sal) + 
              s(temp) + 
              s(ToD) + 
              
              # Structural component
              s(fStation, bs = "re") +         
              s(fCYR, bs = "re") +            
              s(fStation, fCYR, bs = "re") +   
              s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re"), 
            
            data = c_neb5, 
            method = 'fREML', 
            discrete = TRUE, # speed benefit
            family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
            select = TRUE,
            gamma = 1.3)


para_mod <- bam(empty ~
                      SL*fZone +
                      
                      s(sal) + 
                      s(temp) + 
                      s(ToD) + 
                      
                      # Structural component
                      s(fStation, bs = "re") +         
                      s(fCYR, bs = "re") +            
                      s(fStation, fCYR, bs = "re") +   
                      s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re"), 
                    
                    data = c_neb5, 
                    method = 'fREML', 
                    discrete = TRUE, # speed benefit
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                    select = TRUE,
                    gamma = 1.3)


smooth_nointer_mod <- bam(empty ~
                      s(SL) +
                      fZone +
                      
                      s(sal) + 
                      s(temp) + 
                      s(ToD) + 
                      
                      # Structural component
                      s(fStation, bs = "re") +         
                      s(fCYR, bs = "re") +            
                      s(fStation, fCYR, bs = "re") +   
                      s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re"), 
                    
                    data = c_neb5, 
                    method = 'fREML', 
                    discrete = TRUE, # speed benefit
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                    select = TRUE,
                    gamma = 1.3)


smooth_inter_mod <- bam(empty ~
                      s(SL) + 
                      fZone + 
                      s(SL, by=fZone, m=1) + 
                      
                      s(sal) + 
                      s(temp) + 
                      s(ToD) + 
                      
                      # Structural component
                      s(fStation, bs = "re") +         
                      s(fCYR, bs = "re") +            
                      s(fStation, fCYR, bs = "re") +   
                      s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re"), 
                    
                    data = c_neb5, 
                    method = 'fREML', 
                    discrete = TRUE, # speed benefit
                    family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                    select = TRUE,
                    gamma = 1.3)

AIC(no_inter_mod, para_mod, smooth_nointer_mod, smooth_inter_mod)
                         df      AIC
no_inter_mod       23.16266 720.7283
para_mod           25.01311 717.7365
smooth_nointer_mod 25.21533 721.6533
smooth_inter_mod   27.20705 722.3590

BIC(no_inter_mod, para_mod, smooth_nointer_mod, smooth_inter_mod)
                         df      BIC
no_inter_mod       23.16266 825.4379
para_mod           25.01311 830.8114
smooth_nointer_mod 25.21533 835.6422
smooth_inter_mod   27.20705 845.3517

anova(smooth_nointer_mod, smooth_inter_mod, test = "Chisq")
Analysis of Deviance Table

Model 1: empty ~ s(SL) + fZone + s(sal) + s(temp) + s(ToD) + s(fStation, 
    bs = "re") + s(fCYR, bs = "re") + s(fStation, fCYR, bs = "re") + 
    s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re")
Model 2: empty ~ s(SL) + fZone + s(SL, by = fZone, m = 1) + s(sal) + s(temp) + 
    s(ToD) + s(fStation, bs = "re") + s(fCYR, bs = "re") + s(fStation, 
    fCYR, bs = "re") + s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re")
  Resid. Df Resid. Dev     Df Deviance Pr(>Chi)
1    644.53     671.22                         
2    641.95     667.94 2.5795   3.2778   0.2827

summary(smooth_inter_mod)
Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
empty ~ s(SL) + fZone + s(SL, by = fZone, m = 1) + s(sal) + s(temp) + 
    s(ToD) + s(fStation, bs = "re") + s(fCYR, bs = "re") + s(fStation, 
    fCYR, bs = "re") + s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -1.29197    0.25387  -5.089  3.6e-07 ***
fZoneWest     0.09404    0.26074   0.361    0.718    
fZoneWhipray  0.20052    0.50182   0.400    0.689    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                          edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(SL)               1.742e+00      9 32.085  < 2e-16 ***
s(SL):fZoneRankin   1.498e-04      8  0.000 0.245669    
s(SL):fZoneWest     9.991e-06      8  0.000 0.721009    
s(SL):fZoneWhipray  1.146e+00      8  3.023 0.047871 *  
s(sal)              1.236e-05      9  0.000 0.720209    
s(temp)             4.846e-01      9  0.931 0.146920    
s(ToD)              1.682e+00      9 19.385 2.89e-05 ***
s(fStation)         4.388e-05     82  0.000 0.268759    
s(fCYR)             4.945e+00     12 17.802 0.000412 ***
s(fCYR,fStation)    4.276e-05    237  0.000 0.137209    
s(CYR.std,fStation) 7.273e+00     80 13.549 0.004488 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.131   Deviance explained = 13.6%
fREML =  760.9  Scale est. = 1         n = 679
```

Plot of smooth version:

```
> draw(smooth_inter_mod)
```

[image]

```
summary(para_mod)
Family: binomial 
Link function: logit 

Formula:
empty ~ SL * fZone + s(sal) + s(temp) + s(ToD) + s(fStation, 
    bs = "re") + s(fCYR, bs = "re") + s(fStation, fCYR, bs = "re") + 
    s(fStation, CYR.std, bs = "re")

Parametric coefficients:
                 Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)      0.160129   0.498157   0.321  0.74787   
SL              -0.035437   0.011524  -3.075  0.00211 **
fZoneWest        0.183462   0.573610   0.320  0.74909   
fZoneWhipray    -2.613570   1.439108  -1.816  0.06935 . 
SL:fZoneWest    -0.003041   0.014187  -0.214  0.83027   
SL:fZoneWhipray  0.057949   0.024981   2.320  0.02036 * 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                          edf Ref.df Chi.sq  p-value    
s(sal)              1.526e-05      9  0.000 0.698748    
s(temp)             8.885e-01      9  2.465 0.071696 .  
s(ToD)              1.691e+00      9 19.538  2.7e-05 ***
s(fStation)         2.506e-05     82  0.000 0.266617    
s(fCYR)             4.830e+00     12 17.317 0.000483 ***
s(fCYR,fStation)    7.348e-05    237  0.000 0.108609    
s(CYR.std,fStation) 7.572e+00     80 14.262 0.003925 ** 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

R-sq.(adj) =  0.129   Deviance explained = 13.6%
fREML = 767.88  Scale est. = 1         n = 679
```

Sample of data:

```
> example_data <- c_neb5[sample(nrow(c_neb5), 10), ]

> dput(example_data)
structure(list(CYR_Keyfield = c("C-2018-9-15-240", "C-2016-8-14-172", 
"C-2018-10-8-176", "C-2017-8-13-70", "C-2010-7-31-159", "C-2012-8-12-68", 
"C-2018-8-21-279", "C-2017-8-15-237", "C-2019-6-25-240", "C-2019-5-16-254"
), Species = c("Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus", 
"Cynoscion nebulosus", "Cynoscion nebulosus"), ID = c("20189240_54", 
"20168172_42", "201810176_58", "2017870_66", "20107159_1", "2012868_1", 
"20188279_126", "20178237_35", "20196240_114", "20195254_11"), 
    SL = c(29.77, 28.9, 29.97, 24.74, 33.16, 64.96, 52.18, 31.03, 
    26.46, 15.63), empty = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), DateTime = structure(c(1537029540, 
    1471181160, 1539009840, 1502636160, 1280597280, 1344789960, 
    1534864020, 1502801520, 1561476120, 1558012140), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), CYR = c(2018L, 2016L, 2018L, 2017L, 
    2010L, 2012L, 2018L, 2017L, 2019L, 2019L), Month = c(9L, 
    8L, 10L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 5L), DoY = c(258, 227, 281, 
    225, 212, 225, 233, 227, 176, 136), ToD = c(12.65, 9.43333333333333, 
    10.7333333333333, 10.9333333333333, 13.4666666666667, 12.7666666666667, 
    11.1166666666667, 8.86666666666667, 11.3666666666667, 9.15
    ), JDay = c(5108, 4346, 5131, 4710, 2140, 2883, 5083, 4712, 
    5391, 5351), Zone = c("Rankin", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
    "West", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin", "Rankin"), Station = c(240, 
    172, 176, 70, 159, 68, 279, 237, 240, 254), Standard_collection_station = c(0, 
    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Latitude = c(25.088, 25.104, 
    25.1, 25.132, 25.07, 25.121, 25.133, 25.126, 25.088, 25.098
    ), Longitude = c(-80.828, -80.891, -80.866, -80.941, -80.907, 
    -80.955, -80.797, -80.863, -80.828, -80.814), sal = c(37.22, 
    41.15, 36.4099999999999, 43.3, 43.5, 39.6, 34.6, 43, 37.61, 
    37.51), temp = c(32.3459999999998, 28.82, 25.5859999999998, 
    31.05, 34.5, 30.4, 31.1679999999999, 31.4, 33.75, 28.64), 
    fCYR = structure(c(9L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 2L, 4L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L
    ), levels = c("2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", "2013", "2015", 
    "2016", "2017", "2018", "2019", "2021", "2022"), class = "factor"), 
    fMonth = structure(c(7L, 6L, 8L, 6L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
    3L), levels = c("1", "3", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
    "11", "12"), class = "factor"), fStation = structure(c(56L, 
    44L, 48L, 11L, 39L, 10L, 70L, 54L, 56L, 59L), levels = c("20", 
    "21", "22", "23", "24", "40", "54", "65", "67", "68", "70", 
    "71", "73", "101", "105", "106", "107", "111", "112", "117", 
    "118", "119", "122", "123", "124", "130", "133", "134", "135", 
    "137", "143", "144", "145", "146", "147", "156", "157", "158", 
    "159", "167", "168", "169", "171", "172", "173", "174", "175", 
    "176", "224", "225", "226", "227", "229", "237", "239", "240", 
    "241", "253", "254", "255", "256", "257", "265", "266", "267", 
    "268", "269", "270", "278", "279", "280", "281", "282", "284", 
    "290", "291", "292", "294", "301", "302", "312", "609"), class = "factor"), 
    fZone = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), levels = c("Rankin", "West", "Whipray"), class = "factor"), 
    CYR.std = c(9L, 7L, 9L, 8L, 1L, 3L, 9L, 8L, 10L, 10L), center_sl = c(-10.5116053019146, 
    -11.3816053019146, -10.3116053019146, -15.5416053019146, 
    -7.12160530191458, 24.6783946980854, 11.8983946980854, -9.25160530191458, 
    -13.8216053019146, -24.6516053019146)), row.names = c(374L, 
316L, 393L, 432L, 67L, 55L, 584L, 277L, 618L, 91L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I found I shouldn't be comparing models where "SL" is both a linear term and a smooth term - if other studies have found this term to be linear, then it should be linear. Otherwise I shouldn't force linearity and/or re-run essentially the same model as a linear term if I see that "SL" has ~1 EDF; this will result in potentially "overly optimistic p-values." - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/270124/how-to-choose-the-type-of-gam-parameters. Also, because I'm interested in inference, I should only use BIC and be done. I didn't find a resource on how to set "gamma=" though.